# Recreate/Destroy the view in ViewPager - Android

Tags: android

I am using a ViewPager to show images with a custom adapter. When I am in a particular image, I am able to zoom that image. Then I leave that image in the zoomed state and move to the next image. Now when I go back to the previous image, it is still in the zoomed state as I left it. Is there a way to destroy that view or recreate it. So that it wont be left in the zoomed view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean... a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Sorry I mean ViewPager

Comment: Are you using Fragments with `FragmentPagerAdapter` or just a regular `PagerAdapter` with Views?

Comment: Just a regular PagerAdapter with views.

Comment: ...and you're using something like `TouchImageView` for the view with image zoom?

Comment: I am using ZoomableImageView

Comment: Okay, the basic idea is to set an OnPageChangeListener on the ViewPager and when the page changes, reset the views to the left and right of the current page.  If you post your code, I can post a more accurate answer.

Comment: Give me a minute pls.